# How to get a callback from Threadpool executor to finish JobService

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, threadpoolexecutor

My scenario is I need to download 30 zip file each 3 MB and unzip the all the downloaded file when the user is logged in for the first time. As per OREO background restriction, now I am scheduling a job to do this task. But the problem here is if I download all zip sequentially it takes time. I need this task to be run parallel in the background for which I am using thread pool executor to run the thread. But as soon as I use Thread pool Executor I couldn't able to figure out how to stop my job. How can I get a callback saying that all zip files have been downloaded. Is scheduling a job is right way of doing background or should I use Work manager I need this task to be guaranteed executed till the end?

below is threadpool executor class:

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;

import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MyThreadPoolExecutor {
    private static MyThreadPoolExecutor MyThreadPoolExecutor;
    private static int NUMBER_OF_CORES = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    private static final TimeUnit KEEP_ALIVE_TIME_UNIT;
    private final BlockingQueue<Runnable> mDownloadWorkQueue;
    private final ThreadPoolExecutor mDownloadThreadPool;
    private static final int CORE_POOL_SIZE = 8;
    private static final int MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE = 8;
    private static final int KEEP_ALIVE_TIME = 1;
    private Handler mHandler;

    // A static block that sets class fields
    static {

        // The time unit for "keep alive" is in seconds
        KEEP_ALIVE_TIME_UNIT = TimeUnit.SECONDS;

        // Creates a single static instance of PhotoManager
        MyThreadPoolExecutor = new MyThreadPoolExecutor();
    }

    private MyThreadPoolExecutor() {

        mDownloadWorkQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();

        mDownloadThreadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(NUMBER_OF_CORES * 2, NUMBER_OF_CORES * 2,
                KEEP_ALIVE_TIME, KEEP_ALIVE_TIME_UNIT, mDownloadWorkQueue);

        mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {

            /*
             * handleMessage() defines the operations to perform when the
             * Handler receives a new Message to process.
             */
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message inputMessage) {

            }
        };
    }


    public static MyThreadPoolExecutor getInstance() {
        return MyThreadPoolExecutor;
    }


    public void addThread(Runnable runnable){
        mDownloadWorkQueue.add(runnable);
    }

    public void execute(Runnable runnable){
            MyThreadPoolExecutor.mDownloadThreadPool.execute(runnable);

    }


}
```

below is my runnable code :

```
public class SimpleThread implements Runnable {
    private String file_url;

    public SimpleThread( String url) {
        this.file_url = url;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{

            URL url = new URL(file_url.replaceAll(" ", "%20"));
            InputStream fileInputStream = url.openStream();
            if(fileInputStream != null) {
                lessonmediaSaver.save(fileInputStream);
                String source = "path";
                String destination = "destinationpath";
                 new UnzipUtility().unzip(source,destination);

                System.out.println("Saving Zip --> ");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Zip not saved --> ");

            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

this is how i am executing the my jobservice code :

```
for(MyObject myObject:myObjectArray){
                        SimpleThread simpleThread = new SimpleThread(myObject.getFileUrl());
                        IstarThreadPoolExecutor.getInstance().execute(simpleThread);
                    }
```

Comment: Probably you can learn RxJava (`zip`-operator): https://medium.com/mindorks/how-to-make-complex-requests-simple-with-rxjava-in-kotlin-ccec004c5d10, https://riptutorial.com/rx-java/example/10028/making-parallel-requests.

Comment: RxJava can be used in background task ?

Comment: Yes, it is usually used for background tasks. It is used in most modern applications.

Comment: its in kotlin can u pls provide link in java

Comment: Sorry. https://medium.com/code-yoga/using-rxjava-instead-asynctask-3052697c0f48, https://android.jlelse.eu/rxjava-parallelization-concurrency-zip-operator-fe87a36441ff, https://proandroiddev.com/rxjava-mistakes-not-so-parallel-execution-of-blocking-tasks-dcb392a12d03. RxJava is difficult for beginners. Probably you should fix your solution without RxJava.